# How to add a condition to the views.py file in django to not to create the same data objects if it is already present in the database?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, validation

Here's  the *views.py file*:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import News
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Q
# For scraping part
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def news_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # fOR scraping part - START::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    response = requests.get("http://www.iitg.ac.in/home/eventsall/events")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
    cards = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "newsarea"})

    iitg_title = []
    iitg_date = []
    iitg_link = []
    for card in cards[0:6]:
        iitg_date.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ndate"}).text)
        iitg_title.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).text.strip())
        iitg_link.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).a['href'])
    # fOR scraping part - END::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    # fOR storing the scraped data directly into the dtatbase from the views.py file - START---------------------------------------------------------------
    for i in range(len(iitg_title)):
        News.objects.create(title = iitg_title[i], datess = iitg_date[i], linkss = iitg_link[i])
    # fOR storing the scraped data directly into the dtatbase from the views.py file - END-----------------------------------------------------------------

    queryset = News.objects.all()   #Getting all the objects from the database

    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = search_query) |
            Q(description__icontains = search_query)
        )

    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 5)  #Adding pagination
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    queryset = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
       'object_list': queryset
    }

    return render(request, 'news_list.html', context)
```

I have tried different approaches like add the `unique=True` in my model.py file but still doesn't works, throws som,e more error. I am unable to add or figure out the exact condition line of code to be added in the views.py file so that it checks if the data is already there. in the database, and if not present it adds the scraped data else does noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `get_or_create`, e.g. News.objects.get_or_create(title=XYZ), and make the `title` field unique.